# How to make an order in which buttons of different word lengths to be aligned so that every line is about the same length

Tags: html, css

I have 50 buttons with different lengths and I want all the lines to be about the same length. When I use the justify function this doesn't work. Maybe that's because the text in each button is different?

```css
a:link {
  background-color: #F19B42;
  padding: 15px 16px;
  align: "center";
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<a class="a" href="./opdrachtclick.html">Golfen</a> <a class="ab" href="./opdrachtclick.html">Zeilen</a> <a class="ac" href="./opdrachtclick.html">Reizen</a> <a class="ad" href="./opdrachtclick.html">Curacao</a> <a class="ad" href="./opdrachtclick.html">Fotografie</a>
<a class="ae" href="./opdrachtclick.html">Snowboarden</a>
<a class="af" href="./opdrachtclick.html">Programmeren</a> <a class="ag" href="./opdrachtclick.html">Arduino/pi/dialog flow etc. 
    </a> <a class="d" href="./opdrachtclick.html">Innovaties</a> <a class="e" href="./opdrachtclick.html">Leren en inspireren</a> <a class="f" href="./opdrachtclick.html">Klussen / Doe het zelven</a>
<a class="b" href="./opdrachtclick.html">Nieuwe gadgets</a> <a class="ba" href="./opdrachtclick.html">Famillie</a> <a class="da" href="./opdrachtclick.html">ING</a> <a class="ea" href="./opdrachtclick.html">Non-alcohol</a>
```

[image: example how it looks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text-align: justify` will justify text within a tag. Since you applied it to the button themselves, you are justifying the text within the buttons. You need to apply the `text-align: justify` to a wrapper. For example, add a div around your buttons. You'll also need to add `text-align-last: justify`, because `text-align: justify` won't justify the last line. See the snippet below.

```css
div {
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
}

a:link {
  background-color: #F19B42;
  padding: 15px 16px;
  align: "center";
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">Golfen</a>
  <a href="#">Zeilen</a>
  <a href="#">Reizen</a>
  <a href="#">Curacao</a>
  <a href="#">Fotografie</a>
  <a href="#">Snowboarden</a>
  <a href="#">Programmeren</a>
  <a href="#">Arduino/pi/dialog flow etc.</a>
  <a href="#">Innovaties</a>
  <a href="#">Leren en inspireren</a>
  <a href="#">Klussen / Doe het zelven</a>
  <a href="#">Nieuwe gadgets</a>
  <a href="#">Famillie</a>
  <a href="#">ING</a>
  <a href="#">Non-alcohol</a>
</div>
```